# Obtain Int value for position selected from Spinner - android

Tags: android, int, android-spinner

I want to get the int value for the position selected in 4 spinners I have running on my activity. Once I have the Int value I want to loop based off this value and write out a file to the SDCARD, IE spinner1 item 4 selected, produce text files 1, 2, 3, 4 on the sdcard.

I am unsure how to obtain the int value of where the user has clicked in each spinner, but I want to "collect" the values when an imagebutton is selected, currently this is my code;

```
    //used to track spinner value
public int spinner1 = 0;
public int spinner2 = 0;
public int spinner3 = 0;
public int spinner4 = 0;


        etnumber1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.etnumber1);
    etnumber2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.etnumber2);
        etnumber3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.etnumber3);
    etnumber4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.etnumber4);

         etnumber1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
 etnumber2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
 etnumber3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
 etnumber4.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


 }//end of oncreate

     public void onClick(View v) {
      if (v==imagerun) {
           for (int i=1; i<spinner1; i++){
            //primary callsign
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), String.valueOf(i),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 String fileName = String.valueOf(i) +".txt";   
        File myFile = new File("/sdcard/.working/" +fileName);
        myFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile, false);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        myOutWriter.append(etpri1.getText());
        myOutWriter.append(" ");
        myOutWriter.append(String.valueOf(i));
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
        }
        }
         catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

           }//end onclick
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view1, int pos,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        spinner1=etnumber1.getSelectedItemPosition(); // primary number
        spinner2=etnumber2.getSelectedItemPosition(); //secondary 
        spinner3=etnumber3.getSelectedItemPosition(); //primary number 
        spinner4=etnumber4.getSelectedItemPosition(); //secondary number
        }
```

I am clearly doing this wrong, i have tried to follow lots of tutorials but they all refer to getting the string value from a single spinner.  Sorry this is probably a simple request but I have been banging my head against this all day!

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this is it

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view1, int pos,
    long id) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(parent.getId()){
    case R.id.etnumber1:
    {
        spinner1 = pos;
        break;
    }
    case R.id.etnumber2:
    {
        spinner2 = pos;
        break;
    }
    case R.id.etnumber3:
    {
        spinner3 = pos;
        break;
    }
    case R.id.etnumber4:
    {
        spinner4 = pos;
        break;
    }

    }}
```

Comment: This doesnt work i must be missing something. I am unsure how it would be called for each spinner.  Is this complicated because I have 4 spinners on the page?  I tried adding a toast above each break so i could see the value of spinner but nothing displays.

Comment: sorry i edited it shoulda been parent instead of view1 in the switch

Comment: Thanks.  I think i may have got it working by changing my original code from spinner1=etnumber1.getSelectedItemPosition();  to spinner1=adapter.getSelectedItemPosition();

Comment: no problem, thats how i use onItemSelected, theres plenty of ways, i do switch for spinners onClicks, i just think its simpler

Comment: I agree your way is easier to read.  Think I am going to update my code to it.  Thanks again

Answer (score 5):

To get the index selected in a spinner use the following code (using etnumber1 as an example)

```
    int spinnerValue1 = etnumber1.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

and just replicate the code for the other spinners.

Comment: Is that not the same as what i have here  `code`   spinner1=etnumber1.getSelectedItemPosition(); // primary number
        spinner2=etnumber2.getSelectedItemPosition(); //secondary 
        spinner3=etnumber3.getSelectedItemPosition(); //primary number 
        spinner4=etnumber4.getSelectedItemPosition(); //secondary number